# How to understand codes in HERE-API request result

Tags: here-api

I have a HERE-API flow request like this:

```
https://traffic.api.here.com/traffic/6.3/flow.json?app_id=blablablabla&app_code=blablablabla&bbox=-6.616762,%20106.814743;-6.617337,%20106.815086&criticality=minor
```

With result like this:

```
{"RWS":[{"RW":[{"FIS":[{"FI":[{"TMC":{"PC":2622,"DE":"Jalan Durian Raya","QD":"+","LE":0.43409},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":26.5,"SU":26.5,"FF":47.0,"JF":3.7249,"CN":0.78}]},{"TMC":{"PC":2621,"DE":"Jalan Raya Tajur","QD":"+","LE":0.65005},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":20.32,"SU":20.32,"FF":37.9,"JF":3.84588,"CN":0.78}]}]}],"mid":"b454e664-bc01-4ff7-948e-38ea40554fcd|","LI":"C23-02620","DE":"Jalan Raya Pajajaran","PBT":"2018-10-18T09:31:13Z"},{"FIS":[{"FI":[{"TMC":{"PC":2621,"DE":"Jalan Raya Tajur","QD":"-","LE":0.06995},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":16.01,"SU":16.01,"FF":25.5,"JF":2.54451,"CN":0.81}]},{"TMC":{"PC":2622,"DE":"Jalan Durian Raya","QD":"-","LE":0.57022},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":24.1,"SU":24.1,"FF":35.3,"JF":2.32419,"CN":0.81}]},{"TMC":{"PC":2623,"DE":"Jalan Pajajaran Indah Raya","QD":"-","LE":0.43682},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":28.01,"SU":28.01,"FF":40.1,"JF":2.26799,"CN":0.84}]}]}],"mid":"68880e46-f33d-42a0-836c-f22b42765a6a|","LI":"C23+02620","DE":"Jalan Raya Pajajaran","PBT":"2018-10-18T09:31:09Z"},{"FIS":[{"FI":[{"TMC":{"PC":2698,"DE":"Jalan Raya Pajajaran","QD":"-","LE":1.15256},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":21.78,"SU":21.78,"FF":35.9,"JF":3.09603,"CN":0.78}]}]}],"mid":"24eb0f4b-43d8-4048-974b-3ad21e6d4075|","LI":"C23+02695","DE":"Jalan Raya Tajur","PBT":"2018-10-18T09:31:13Z"},{"FIS":[{"FI":[{"TMC":{"PC":2698,"DE":"Jalan Raya Pajajaran","QD":"+","LE":0.05673},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":8.67,"SU":8.67,"FF":27.6,"JF":8.13035,"CN":0.75}]},{"TMC":{"PC":2697,"DE":"Jalan Dahlia","QD":"+","LE":1.07164},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":15.91,"SU":15.91,"FF":38.7,"JF":6.97436,"CN":0.71}]}]}],"mid":"04e46740-d1c1-4d3b-b362-c8385f7ba83c|","LI":"C23-02695","DE":"Jalan Raya Tajur","PBT":"2018-10-18T09:31:26Z"},{"FIS":[{"FI":[{"TMC":{"PC":8478,"DE":"Jalan Parung Banteng","QD":"+","LE":0.03168},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":13.99,"SU":13.99,"FF":17.0,"JF":0.0,"CN":0.7}]},{"TMC":{"PC":8477,"DE":"Jalan Durian Raya","QD":"+","LE":0.0742},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":13.0,"SU":13.0,"FF":21.0,"JF":2.38095,"CN":0.7}]}]}],"mid":"ec286d55-3452-458b-bcce-249ef46b8b17|","LI":"C23-08476","DE":"Jalan Cempedak Raya","PBT":"2018-10-18T09:31:41Z"},{"FIS":[{"FI":[{"TMC":{"PC":8477,"DE":"Jalan Durian Raya","QD":"-","LE":0.03512},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":12.0,"SU":12.0,"FF":21.0,"JF":2.85714,"CN":0.7}]},{"TMC":{"PC":8478,"DE":"Jalan Parung Banteng","QD":"-","LE":0.07076},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":8.01,"SU":8.01,"FF":17.5,"JF":3.71428,"CN":0.7}]}]}],"mid":"316164f0-3b40-4c1f-8368-cee4433b6637|","LI":"C23+08476","DE":"Jalan Cempedak Raya","PBT":"2018-10-18T09:31:41Z"},{"FIS":[{"FI":[{"TMC":{"PC":8577,"DE":"Jalan Raya Pajajaran","QD":"+","LE":0.07311},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":12.0,"SU":12.0,"FF":19.0,"JF":2.10526,"CN":0.7}]},{"TMC":{"PC":8576,"DE":"Jalan Cempedak Raya","QD":"+","LE":0.56327},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":13.0,"SU":13.0,"FF":23.1,"JF":3.07359,"CN":0.7}]}]}],"mid":"357f85f1-209e-4718-864c-0ecea6dfe68a|","LI":"C23-08575","DE":"Jalan Durian Raya","PBT":"2018-10-18T09:31:41Z"},{"FIS":[{"FI":[{"TMC":{"PC":8576,"DE":"Jalan Cempedak Raya","QD":"-","LE":0.04608},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":17.0,"SU":17.0,"FF":20.0,"JF":0.0,"CN":0.7}]},{"TMC":{"PC":8577,"DE":"Jalan Raya Pajajaran","QD":"-","LE":0.5903},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":13.99,"SU":13.99,"FF":22.8,"JF":2.54385,"CN":0.7}]}]}],"mid":"3183f70b-ae99-43dc-9275-9ff66bf08c30|","LI":"C23+08575","DE":"Jalan Durian Raya","PBT":"2018-10-18T09:31:41Z"},{"FIS":[{"FI":[{"TMC":{"PC":8914,"DE":"Jalan Parung Banteng","QD":"-","LE":0.02799},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":11.0,"SU":11.0,"FF":14.0,"JF":0.0,"CN":0.7}]},{"TMC":{"PC":8915,"DE":"Jalan Pajajaran Indah Raya/Jalan Tunjung Biru","QD":"-","LE":0.92454},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":12.98,"SU":12.98,"FF":16.1,"JF":0.07209,"CN":0.73}]}]}],"mid":"92a561d1-1857-477a-a5e7-8930a8e65fa3|","LI":"C23+08913","DE":"Jalan Pajajaran Indah V","PBT":"2018-10-18T09:31:41Z"},{"FIS":[{"FI":[{"TMC":{"PC":8914,"DE":"Jalan Parung Banteng","QD":"+","LE":0.95254},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":14.38,"SU":14.38,"FF":16.4,"JF":0.0,"CN":0.71}]}]}],"mid":"94e9f95c-c2f3-4385-940c-030263a955f2|","LI":"C23-08913","DE":"Jalan Pajajaran Indah V","PBT":"2018-10-18T09:31:41Z"},{"FIS":[{"FI":[{"TMC":{"PC":8953,"DE":"Jalan Cempedak Raya/Jalan Pajajaran Indah V","QD":"+","LE":1.1729},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":13.99,"SU":13.99,"FF":18.4,"JF":0.76086,"CN":0.7}]}]}],"mid":"28d7ef32-9bf4-49f2-8289-0ed52c0de94a|","LI":"C23-08952","DE":"Jalan Parung Banteng","PBT":"2018-10-18T09:31:41Z"},{"FIS":[{"FI":[{"TMC":{"PC":8953,"DE":"Jalan Cempedak Raya/Jalan Pajajaran Indah V","QD":"-","LE":0.03956},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":13.99,"SU":13.99,"FF":16.2,"JF":0.0,"CN":0.7}]},{"TMC":{"PC":8954,"DE":"Bogor 1","QD":"-","LE":1.13334},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":13.0,"SU":13.0,"FF":18.8,"JF":1.48936,"CN":0.7}]}]}],"mid":"45f7aa3b-0cb6-4ddc-9c5a-4149b5f9648b|","LI":"C23+08952","DE":"Jalan Parung Banteng","PBT":"2018-10-18T09:31:41Z"},{"FIS":[{"FI":[{"TMC":{"PC":24124,"DE":"Jalan Siliwangi","QD":"+","LE":0.03148},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":13.67,"SU":13.67,"FF":19.0,"JF":1.22073,"CN":0.72}]},{"TMC":{"PC":24123,"DE":"Jalan Saleh Danasasnita","QD":"+","LE":0.97711},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":21.86,"SU":21.86,"FF":29.1,"JF":1.45539,"CN":0.82}]}]}],"mid":"47235aea-f54b-46df-9f15-03f0c913e52a|","LI":"C23-24122","DE":"Jalan Lawang Gintung","PBT":"2018-10-18T09:31:02Z"},{"FIS":[{"FI":[{"TMC":{"PC":24127,"DE":"Jalan Pahlawan","QD":"+","LE":0.5877},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":11.82,"SU":11.82,"FF":27.2,"JF":5.46778,"CN":0.79}]},{"TMC":{"PC":24126,"DE":"Jalan Saleh Danasasnita","QD":"+","LE":1.03899},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":21.78,"SU":21.78,"FF":29.0,"JF":1.4555,"CN":0.82}]}]}],"mid":"8dfb675e-cd62-4e0e-8fa1-913febbf3dd1|","LI":"C23-24125","DE":"Jalan Batu Tulis","PBT":"2018-10-18T09:31:13Z"},{"FIS":[{"FI":[{"TMC":{"PC":24124,"DE":"Jalan Siliwangi","QD":"-","LE":1.81806},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":16.12,"SU":16.12,"FF":27.8,"JF":3.1217,"CN":0.77}]}]}],"mid":"6fdc5622-6392-478d-aedc-356009d885f3|","LI":"C23+24122","DE":"Jalan Lawang Gintung","PBT":"2018-10-18T09:31:19Z"},{"FIS":[{"FI":[{"TMC":{"PC":24154,"DE":"Jalan Sukasan I","QD":"-","LE":0.24046},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":14.77,"SU":14.77,"FF":27.0,"JF":3.42004,"CN":0.84}]},{"TMC":{"PC":24155,"DE":"Jalan Lawang Gintung","QD":"-","LE":0.38831},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":10.68,"SU":10.68,"FF":28.3,"JF":7.10283,"CN":0.76}]},{"TMC":{"PC":24156,"DE":"Jalan Raya Tajur/Jalan Raya Pajajaran","QD":"-","LE":0.27849},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":9.65,"SU":9.65,"FF":25.5,"JF":6.76531,"CN":0.75}]}]}],"mid":"710c2348-f63f-48c1-a91b-0a3178df92be|","LI":"C23+24151","DE":"Jalan Siliwangi","PBT":"2018-10-18T09:31:01Z"},{"FIS":[{"FI":[{"TMC":{"PC":24156,"DE":"Jalan Raya Tajur/Jalan Raya Pajajaran","QD":"+","LE":0.04761},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":9.99,"SU":9.99,"FF":21.0,"JF":3.81175,"CN":0.8}]},{"TMC":{"PC":24155,"DE":"Jalan Lawang Gintung","QD":"+","LE":0.24403},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":14.35,"SU":14.35,"FF":26.3,"JF":3.40337,"CN":0.79}]},{"TMC":{"PC":24154,"DE":"Jalan Sukasan I","QD":"+","LE":1.54185},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":20.61,"SU":20.61,"FF":28.0,"JF":1.56765,"CN":0.8}]}]}],"mid":"568b5b32-49cc-440f-a8b6-703268da32c1|","LI":"C23-24151","DE":"Jalan Siliwangi","PBT":"2018-10-18T09:31:06Z"},{"FIS":[{"FI":[{"TMC":{"PC":27746,"DE":"Jalan Pajajaran/Jalan Raya Pajajaran","QD":"+","LE":0.0485},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":11.0,"SU":11.0,"FF":28.0,"JF":6.66666,"CN":0.7}]},{"TMC":{"PC":27745,"DE":"Jalan Siliwangi","QD":"+","LE":0.38998},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":8.99,"SU":8.99,"FF":28.4,"JF":8.13203,"CN":0.78}]}]}],"mid":"7288833c-cca1-43d1-8e46-684d359cf6b0|","LI":"C23-27744","DE":"Jalan Sukasan I","PBT":"2018-10-18T09:31:41Z"},{"FIS":[{"FI":[{"TMC":{"PC":27745,"DE":"Jalan Siliwangi","QD":"-","LE":0.04268},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":24.68,"SU":24.68,"FF":17.0,"JF":0.0,"CN":0.73}]},{"TMC":{"PC":27746,"DE":"Jalan Pajajaran/Jalan Raya Pajajaran","QD":"-","LE":0.3958},"SHP":[],"CF":[{"TY":"TR","SP":21.43,"SU":21.43,"FF":25.3,"JF":0.34253,"CN":0.72}]}]}],"mid":"b0f4bfc0-9ed7-4391-86e9-12f0aa6b1963|","LI":"C23+27744","DE":"Jalan Sukasan I","PBT":"2018-10-18T09:31:41Z"}],"TY":"TMC","MAP_VERSION":"201804","EBU_COUNTRY_CODE":"C","EXTENDED_COUNTRY_CODE":"F2","TABLE_ID":"23","UNITS":"metric"}],"MAP_VERSION":"","CREATED_TIMESTAMP":"2018-10-18T09:31:41.000+0000","VERSION":"3.2.2","UNITS":"metric"}
```

There are codes in this result and I don't understand what it says.
Is there a documentation that explain it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to Here Traffic API Documentation to get the response elements and meanings documentation.developer.here.com/pdf/traffic_hlp/6.0.85.0/Traffic%20API%20v6.0.85.0%20Developer's%20Guide.pdf.  You can also go to https://developer.here.com/documentation/versions and download this file.

Comment: hi HERE, I can not get the file.

Comment: please use https://developer.here.com/documentation/versions to see the documentation for all Here products and services.